# Python Trello API to update Cover Color on a card

Tags: python, api, trello

Trello have added ability to put a 'cover' on individual cards.  This can be a solid color or an image.

Per their API, you should be able to update this via a PUT request.  See [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/#api-cards-id-put) which talks about updating a card, and includes the 'cover'.  The Card contains a number of data items (json), such as:

> "desc": "old desc",
>
> "cover": {
> "brightness": "light",
> "color": null,
> "idAttachment": null,
> "idUploadedBackground": null,
> "size": "normal"
> },

I'm able up update other details on the card, eg the 'desc' via a PUT, eg as follows:

```
import requests
url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{myCardID}"
query = {'key': "{myAPIkey}", 'token': "{myToken}"}
payload = {'desc': 'new desc',}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, params=query, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

This successfully updates the desc to 'new desc' as follows:

> "desc": "new desc",

I cant work out what I need to pass to update the Cover color.  I think I should be able to pass this in the code above but it doesnt work.

```
payload = {'cover': {'color': 'purple'} }
```

I always get null for the color in the cover object.

> "cover": {
> "brightness": "light",
> "color": null,
> "idAttachment": null,
> "idUploadedBackground": null,
> "size": "normal"
> },

**What do I need to pass as the data/payload in my PUT request ????**

*note:  valid colors are 'pink', 'yellow', 'lime', 'blue', 'black', 'orange', 'red', 'purple', 'sky', 'green'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following code worked for me:

```py
headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{card_id}/cover"

params = {"key":key,"token":token,"value":{'idAttachment': None,
 'color': 'purple',
 'idUploadedBackground': None,
 'size': 'full',
 'brightness': 'light'}}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, json=params)
```

Replace the right card id within the url,

Good luck

Comment: A-ha ... thank you!!     The missing link ... their API seems to need to have the 'cover' passed via the 'json' parameter in the request, and not via params or data parameters (as are used in the Trello API documentation/code sample).  
  
Changing the parameter to json, and leaving the url as the card endpoint, lets me change any of the card data at the same time.

Comment: Yes, their documentation is not accurate