# Trello - Updating a cards position and color at the same time

Tags: python, python-requests, trello

I'm trying to have my board update based on some results and having a hard time finding the best way to update both a card's position and the color. The idea is to have a card update based on a result, red and to the top to catch my attention; but if everything is working correctly, then green and to the bottom.

So far I have:

```
def updateCard():
    url = f"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{CARD_ID}/cover"

    headers = {
       "Accept": "application/json"
    }

    query = {
       'key': API_KEY,
       'token': OAUTH_TOKEN,
       'name': 'New Title',
       'desc': 'New Description',
       'pos': 'bottom',
       'value': {'color': 'green'}
    }

    response = requests.request(
       "PUT",
       url,
       headers=headers,
       json=query
    )

    print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

The pseudo code is from: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/trello/rest/api-group-cards/#api-cards-id-put and added my own variables.

I noticed that for changing the color, I need to pass the json variable in the response, and have the URL end with '/cover'. However, this does not work when trying to update the position. If I take the `/cover` out of the URL, then the position gets updated. Is there a way to have both update at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround to this issue so far (and if anyone has a better syntax, feel free to add a comment):

```
url = f"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{CARD_ID}"
url_cover = f"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{CARD_ID}/cover"

headers = {
   "Accept": "application/json"
}

query = {
   'key': API_KEY,
   'token': OAUTH_TOKEN,
   'name': 'New Title 3',
   'desc': 'New Description',
   'pos': 'top'
}

json = {
        'key': API_KEY,
        'token': OAUTH_TOKEN,
        'value': {
        'brightness': 'dark',
        'color': card_color,
        'size': 'full'}}

response = requests.request(
   "PUT",
   url,
   headers=headers,
   params=query
)

response = requests.request(
   "PUT",
   url_cover,
   headers=headers,
   json=json
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Trello's API, and I can't test it without setting up a developer account, but my instinct is that you might be able to change your query like so:

```
. . .

url = f"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{CARD_ID}"

. . .

query = {
       'key': API_KEY,
       'token': OAUTH_TOKEN,
       'value': {
           'name': 'New Title',
           'desc': 'New Description',
           'pos': 'bottom',
           'cover': {'color': 'green'}
       }
    }
```

It looks like "cover" is a nested object under the "card" object, so you can just put an object in that field. When you're updating the card's position, you should be going for the card object directly, not the `/cover` field. You would use the `/cover` endpoint if you intended your request only to be scoped to the cover of the card.

**EDIT: Trying a new request format**

Comment: Hi Austin, 

That's the thing (and confusing part), passing the above query does not update the actual `/cover` endpoint which is bizarre. My way around it has been:
`url = f"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{CARD_ID}"`
`url_cover = f"https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{CARD_ID}/cover"`

Then pass the request twice, which in my opinion does not make any sense. As you can see from this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555911/python-trello-api-to-update-cover-color-on-a-card) they had a similar issue but still highlighting the `/cover` endpoint.

Comment: @CJL89, I followed that link to the other SO post and I agree with you... it looks like they're having the same exact issue. And someone in the comments mentions that Trello's API documentation doesn't appear to be accurate.

However, I'm noticing that they did something a little different in their post... they wrap all of the variables into the "value" key. I didn't notice this at first. Can you try that and let me know what happens? (see edit in my post)

Comment: Hi @Austin, I actually tried that and it passes normally. 
For some reason changing the key name to `values` works properly too as long as you point to `/cover`. Once you point to the main card, you can't access any values of the dictionary that you call within `/cover` anymore.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate! Perhaps Trello's API can't pull this off at the moment?

Comment: It seems to be the case at the moment and documentation sucks, so I think extra lines will have to do the trick.
Thanks for your help!